# modifyEntrySources hook, comparing two field values

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

Is it possible with the modifyEntrySources hook to query a field value against another fields value? Example:

Two fields are present on the entry section this hook targets

- fieldParentId
- fieldId

I want to be able to query in the entry source definition if the `fieldParentId` is the same as the `fieldId` to return only those records in the entry list within Craft that match this. I'm not sure this is possible, or if there is a special syntax required within the `criteria` array to do it?

Comment: It is possible to do this with Craft 3 since you work with queries directly, you'll need an ugly work around with Craft 2 because you can't create such a condition via array by default, so you'll need to overwrite and extend more things

Comment: I'm on Craft 2 for now. I ended up having to perform a ElementCriterialModel query and return  all entries in the section then in a foreach do a comparison with the two fields and return the ids that all matched to use in the entry source criteria. Not ideal but does the job.

Comment: @JamesWhite Could you add the solution you ended up on as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround solution was to essentially do an criteria on the section, return all the records, use a conditional to find out which records have the same "parent ID" and ID", stores those in an array and then use the id criteria for the entry source.

Something like:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'theSection';
$criteria->limit = null;
$articles = $criteria->find();

// For storing matching entries on the conditional below
$ids = [];

foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
     if($entry->fieldParentId == $entry->fieldId)
     {
         array_push($ids, $entry->id);
     }
}
```

This will then provide a list of ids that match the required criteria, which can then be used for a specific entry source.

This has performance issues though, because you have to get the entire list of entries first each time.

Comment: So why don't you query for entries with the same columns from the beginning and return only the ids? You can transform the criteria model into a query and include normal `where` conditions. Otherwise you might run into performance issues sooner or later

Comment: @RobinSchambach I'd agree that's a better way. We ended up changing the structure of the records, so we didn't have to do this in the end, but a query would be more performance friendly.